# customize bash tab-completion to show a list of matching substrings until the next ambiguity

Tags: bash, tab-completion, completion

default bash tab-completion completes the common prefix until first ambiguity, and shows a list of all available matches. For example:

```
$ ls
foo_a1 foo_a2 foo_bb1 foo_bb2
$ ls ./foo_<TAB><TAB>
foo_a1 foo_a2 foo_bb1 foo_bb2
```

I would like to change this. Instead of showing the complete list of all available matching options, i would like to show all unique prefixes of the matches, but stopping at the next ambiguity. This way, the number of completions is smaller because completions do not include branching of matches at further points of ambiguity. In the above example, bash would recognize that after "foo_" there are 4 matches but only two unique completions ("a" and "bb") until next ambiguity ("1" vs "2"). The user would see this:

```
$ ls
foo_a1 foo_a2 foo_bb1 foo_bb2
$ ls ./foo_<TAB><TAB>
foo_a foo_bb
```

I've searched far and wide but no cigar. I read the manual of readline but there doesn't seem to be an option that implements this.

How can I achieve the desired behavior? Is it possible to configure bash to do the above? If not, does anyone know of an autocompletion tool that supports the above functionality? If so, is it possible to change the autocompletion mechanism to something else than readline?

Comment: i tried your example `$ ls ./<TAB><TAB>` and it did not give me `foo_a1 foo_a2 foo_bb1 foo_bb2`. please update.

Comment: Thats almost certainly baked in at a low level in the source code of bash (will be glad to be wrong). A good project to learn some coding skills for you. Good luck.

Comment: i dont think it can work as you expected. when `ls ./foo_<TAB><TAB>` gives you `foo_a  foo_bb` you even cannot tell if there's a file named `foo_a`.

Comment: @pynexj updated the example. The particular behavior depends on user's setting of readline. I updated the example so that it matches the default behavior on rhel.

Comment: `I've searched far and wide but no cigar` Did you start writing your own completion function for `ls`? `doesn't seem to be an option that implements this.` There isn't. If you want it, you have to implement it. I think you can either modify the `ls` shell completion, or you can modify readline source code. There is no question in your post. In the spirit of this forum, consider asking a question? You might be interested in fish shell for  better user experience.

Comment: @KamilCuk I did not. Also clarifying, I'd like bash tab completion to work as described for path completions in all contexts, not just when using `ls`.

Comment: "The particular behavior depends on user's setting of readline." -- readline does not have such feature. you need to write your own completion spec.